# Delete blinking cursor in a textField

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have a pickerView in a textField.

Problem is how to hide blinking cursor after a word in the textField when I choose the row.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "When I choose the row"?

Comment: @NSNoob in pickerView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do using setting the color of your textfield

**Objective C:**

```
[[self yourtextField] setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

**Swift:**

```
self.yourtextField().tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using following code in `didSelectRow`:

`[yourTextField resignFirstResponder]`

Comment: this is the next thing after set tint color to white, thanks